# Getting the lastChild from document

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Do not judge strictly. This is a test code for training. I can not figure out why the last element of the `ul` tag does not appear by the `getElementsByTagName`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <div>Users:</div>
  <ul>
    <li>Max</li>
    <li>Daniel</li>
  </ul>
dsfsdf
  <script>
   var head = document.head.firstChild; // work good

   alert(head);

    var ul = document.body.getElementsByTagName("ul").lastChild; // undefined

    alert(ul);

  </script>

</body>

</html>

<!-- <script src="test.js"></script> -->
```

Comment: What is `GetNumericVitagName`?

Comment: Sorry, copy-past another func. I mean `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: Look at what .getElementsByTagName returns. :)

Comment: `document.body.querySelector("ul li:last-child")`

Comment: Note that even if you had selected just the `ul`, the `.lastChild` would give you a text node representing the whitespace characters at the end of the `ul` content. To get the `li`, you'd use `.lastElementChild`

Comment: `document.body.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].lastChild`

Comment: @askovpen: See my comment above yours. You need `.lastElementChild`